# Sum of probabilities equal expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, stopping-times

On page 18 of Norris book he writes the equality

$$
\sum_n^{\infty} P_i(H^A\geq n) =E_i(H^A)
$$

And he previously noted the expectation to equal

$$
E_i(H^A)=\sum_n^{\infty}n P(H^A) 
$$

I am not sure how it can be formally shown that the first equality holds and how to prove that it is also equivalent for the second line.

Here

$H^A = inf\{n \geq 0: X_n \in A\}$

Is the hitting time of set A and X_n is the relevant Markov Chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X\ge 0$ is non-negative random variable supported on the integers we have that
$$
EX=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X>n)
$$
To see this, note that
$$
EX=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n P(X=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=1}^n1\right ) P(X=n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{n=i}^\infty P(X=n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X>i-1)
$$
where the interchanging of order of summation is allowed because we are dealing with non-negative series.

Comment: Wow. Is it me or is this completely non intuitive? Is there any intuition to be gained here or is it just a trick?

Comment: Also, this makes me suspect the book as a typo in that $nP(..)$ should really be $nP_i(..) $